# davsf2 auto mount on startup with root

Tags: mount, root, reboot, davfs2

I have a folder that I want to be mounted all the time. But when the server reboots the mount will be lost.

So I followed this tutorial: [link](http://techiech.blogspot.nl/2013/04/mounting-webdav-directory-in-linux.html)

Now, I don't use users and I do everything on my root. So I changed:

```
secrets ~/.davfs2/secrets
```

to:

```
/etc/davfs2/secrets
```

I did do this on the other places aswell.
And I did skip the part where I had to add users.
Now, when I type:

```
mount /var/stack
```

I will get the error:

```
/sbin/mount.davfs:/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf:36: unknown option
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that running everything as root isn't a good idea (some programs won't even start because it's so bad) it might be useful to show us your `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf`

Comment: There is nothing in it changed, only uncommented one line of code and changed the path: 
`secrets         /etc/davfs2/secrets`